# C# Visual Studio 2013 live semantic error but compile complete

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I use Visual Studio 2013 update 4 write c# code.
IDE show live semantic error, where I use another project Extensions method.
But I can compile complete, and run application successfully.
Any idea to fix this problem ?
Thans a lot

[image]

Comment: Finally, I remove all references which point to solution project. 
Add reference then again. 
IDE live semantic is working correctly.